# Рандомизировать последовательность вывода элементов двумерного массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Помогите пожалуйста - вторые сутки голову ломаю, проблема в следующем - как сделать вывод **теста** (вопрос-варианты ответов) так, чтобы вопросы и варианты ответов каждый раз строились в рандомном порядке?
Пробовал `array_rand` и `shuffle` - рандомизирует вывод только ответов:

```
echo '<b> Who are you? </b><br />';
$numbers1 = ["Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank"];
shuffle($numbers1);
foreach ($numbers1 as $number) {
    echo $number.'<br />';
}
echo '<br />';
echo '<b> How old you? </b><br />';
$numbers2 = ['10', '25', '40', '60', '90'];
shuffle($numbers2);
foreach ($numbers2 as $number) {
    echo $number.'<br />';
}
```

Обязательным условием стоит - все данные должны быть в **массивах**!
Заранее большое человеческое спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рандомизирует только вывод ответов, потому что вывод вопросов задан жестко.

Раз просите сделать все массивами, почему сами не придерживались этого правила?

Вот алгоритм:

1. Нужно создать массив, где ключи — это вопросы, а значения — варианты ответов.
2. Затем необходимо получить ключи массива (вопросы) и перемешать.
3. После этого нужно перебрать все вопросы и найти связанные с ними ответы.
4. На последнем шаге надо не забыть перемешать и вывести ответы.

Помните о том, что [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php) изменяет ключи массива.

[Код примера на Ideone](http://ideone.com/WFreD3)

```
<?php

$test = [
  'Who are you?' => ["Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank"],
  'How old are you?' => ['10', '25', '40', '60', '90']
];

$questions = array_keys($test);

shuffle($questions);

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    $answers = $test[$question];
    shuffle($answers);

    echo "<b>{$question}</b><br/>";
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        echo "{$answer}<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Список вопросов у Вас задан "захардкоден" в верстке, поэтому чтобы вопросы были в массиве, их просто нужно туда добавить. Вот пример:

```
$questions = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Вопрос 1",
        "answers" => array(
            "1" => "Ответ 1",
            "2" => "Ответ 2",
            "3" => "Ответ 3",
        ),
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Вопрос 2",
        "answers" => array(
            "1" => "Ответ 1",
            "2" => "Ответ 2",
            "3" => "Ответ 3",
        ),
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Вопрос 3",
        "answers" => array(
            "1" => "Ответ 1",
            "2" => "Ответ 2",
            "3" => "Ответ 3",
        ),
    )
);
?>
<?php shuffle($questions); ?>
<?php foreach ($questions as $question): ?>
    <div>
        <b><?php echo $question["name"]; ?></b>
        <?php shuffle($question["answers"]); ?>
        <ol>
            <?php foreach ($question["answers"] as $answer): ?>
                <li><?php echo $answer; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
```